# Mongoose/Mongodb, update each doc query, very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this update query in mongoose. It's 1600 posts and takes like 5 min to run.

What's the bottleneck? Am I using the wrong approach?

```
export const getAndStoreLatestKPI = async () => {
  console.log("start kpi");
  try {
    const marketCaps = await getKPI();
    const stocks = await mongoose.model("stock").find().exec();

    for (const stock of stocks) {
      const marketCap = marketCaps.find(
        (marketCap) => marketCap.i === stock.insId
      );

      if (marketCap != null) {
        const marketCapAdjustedVal =
          stock.country === "Finland" ? marketCap.n * 10 : marketCap.n;

        const update = {
          marketCap: marketCapAdjustedVal,
        };
        console.log(marketCapAdjustedVal);
        await mongoose
          .model("stock")
          .findOneAndUpdate({ insId: stock.insId }, { update });
      }
    }
    console.log("done");
    return Promise.resolve();
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};

export const getKPI = async (kpiId: number) => {
  try {
    const kpiFetch = await Axios.get(someurl);
    return Promise.resolve(kpiFetch.data.values);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: What is `marketCaps`? is it another collection? why don't you wait for the promise returned from it?

Comment: I fetch it from an external api. I have await on it?

Comment: No, or yes. it depend if the API returns a promise or not.I guess if it's working for you then you don't have to wait on it

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I've added the getKPI function. Is it returning a promise?

Comment: an `async` function by default always returns a promise. even if the actual function isn't actually doing anything async. (which in this case is not true as `Axios.get` is async).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main bottle neck is your `for` loop. for each stock item you perform several "expensive" actions such as data fetching from external API + a single update, and you're doing them 1 by 1.

What I would recommend you doing is looping on several items at once. similar to the idea [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)).
There are several different solutions on how to do it in `nodejs` for example `nodejs` [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

However I personally use and recommend using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) which gives you this ability and many others straight out of the box.

Some sample code:

```
import Bluebird = require('bluebird');
const stocks = await mongoose.model("stock").find().exec();

await Bluebird.map(stocks, async (stock) => {
     const marketCap = marketCaps.find(
        (marketCap) => marketCap.i === stock.insId
      );

      if (marketCap != null) {
        const marketCapAdjustedVal =
          stock.country === "Finland" ? marketCap.n * 10 : marketCap.n;

        const update = {
          marketCap: marketCapAdjustedVal,
        };
        console.log(marketCapAdjustedVal);
        await mongoose
          .model("stock")
          .findOneAndUpdate({ insId: stock.insId }, { update });
      }
}, {concurrency: 25})
// concurrency details how many concurrent process run parallel. the heavier they are the less you want concurrent for obvious reasons.
```

Comment: The external API call is not in the for-loop. Isn't ES Promise.all same thing as bluebird?

Comment: You can use the native `Promise.all` but you can't control the `concurrency` rate. this can lead in most cases to `OOM` errors in your processes